# Muchomor cipher

Tags: block-cipher, symmetric, reference-request

I've been given a task to research and possibly implement so called 'Muchomor' cipher.  Has anybody ever heard of this cipher? I've found only one article about it and it was in Russian. I'm quite fluent in Russian so I was able to read it; however, it was still not enough. I would appreciate any data about where to look for this cipher. As far as I know, it's a block symmetric cipher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A symmetric cipher design contest was started in Ukraine around 2006, and this cipher (in Ukrainian and Russian: **Мухомор**) was there.

For specifications, look for "Applied Radioelectronics" journal "Прикладная радиоэлектроника", 2007, No 2.

- http://anpre.org.ua/?q=pre_2007_2
- http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/61794/06-Dolgov.pdf

A competition overview in English was given at CECC 2009 by Roman Oliynykov:

- http://conf.fme.vutbr.cz/cecc09/index.php?stranka=lectures